# Have Angular function conditionally call anchor tag

Tags: html, angular, rxjs

I have a dialog box, with a conditional button.  When all of the conditions are met, the button calls a function to perform the desired action (This all works fine).

Alternatively, if all of the conditions are not met, clicking the button displays an error banner in the dialog (This all works fine too).

However, when viewed on a small screen, since the button is at the bottom of the dialog box, when the error banner is displayed the user has to manually scroll to the top of the dialog, to view the error.

How can I get the error button to navigate to the top of the dialog (anchor tag?) when all of the conditions are not met?

Here was my initial (failed) attempt:

```
export class MyComponent {

...

    @ViewChild('dialogTitle')
    private dialogTitleRef!: ElementRef(HTMLLinkElement);

...

    myFunction(id: string): void {
        if (this.myForm.valid) {
            <perform my action>
            this.myDialog.close(id);
        } else {
            this.displayError = true;
            this.dialogTitleRef.nativeElement.scrollIntoView();
    }
}
```

Comment: if the banner appears at the top of the window, you could call `window.scroll(0,0)`. Alternatively, you could use sticky positioning to pin the banner to the top of the viewport

Comment: Thanks Tanner for the response.

I tried your solution.  Unfortunately, the banner appears within the dialog, which itself, floats over the page.  Scrolling to the top of the page re-positions the parent page behind the dialog.  It does not change the position of the users' view of the dialog.

Comment: Does the error appear inside the `myDialog` component, or inside `MyComponent`? What is `dialogTitleRef`?

Comment: Thanks for inquiring.  The error appears as a banner above the dialog title (dialogTitle) of 'myDialog'.  'dialogTitleRef' is an element reference to the 'dialogTitle' element, as defined at the component level with the '@ViewChild' decorator as shown.

But, I don't need to do this with an element reference.  If an anchor tag or position reference will work, that is fine too.  What ever shifts the view to the top of the dialog.